# How to clear up unmet peer dependency errors in an exponent project

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native, exponentjs

I started with a basic exponent starter project and followed their tutorial to add an apollo client and ended up with a bunch of peer depenendency issues.  How can I fix it - do I need to pin certain versions of apollo client?  What is the conflict?

adding the apollo client references as per this guide: https://docs.getexponent.com/versions/v12.0.0/guides/using-apollo.html

Here's the single peer dependency error with the exponent starter project from the outset (do I need to fix that somehow - exponent is pinned to react 15.3.2)?

```
$ npm ls --depth 0

vanilla-exponent@0.0.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent
├── @exponent/ex-navigation@2.3.0
├── @exponent/samples@1.0.2
├── @exponent/vector-icons@2.0.3
├── exponent@12.0.5
├── jest-exponent@0.1.4
├── react@15.3.2
└── react-native@0.37.0 (git+https://github.com/exponentjs/react-native.git#e708008e450ce254e715b7034b6fd63346974c6c)

npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^15.4.1, required by react-test-renderer@15.4.1
```

And all the warnings after I run `npm install apollo-client react-apollo --save`

```
$ npm ls --depth 0

vanilla-exponent@0.0.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent
├── @exponent/ex-navigation@2.3.0
├── @exponent/samples@1.0.2
├── @exponent/vector-icons@2.0.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY apollo-client@0.7.1
├── exponent@12.0.5
├── jest-exponent@0.1.4
├── react@15.3.2
├── react-apollo@0.8.1
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-dom@0.14.x || 15.* || ^15.0.0
├── react-native@0.37.0 invalid
├── react-native-maps@0.11.0 extraneous
└── react-native-svg@4.3.0 extraneous

npm ERR! peer dep missing: apollo-client@^0.6.0, required by react-apollo@0.8.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react-dom@0.14.x || 15.* || ^15.0.0, required by react-apollo@0.8.1
npm ERR! invalid: react-native@0.37.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/react-native
npm ERR! extraneous: absolute-path@0.0.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/absolute-path
npm ERR! extraneous: art@0.10.1 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/art
npm ERR! extraneous: babel-plugin-external-helpers@6.18.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/babel-plugin-external-helpers
npm ERR! extraneous: babel-polyfill@6.20.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/babel-polyfill
npm ERR! extraneous: babel-preset-es2015-node@6.1.1 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015-node
npm ERR! extraneous: babel-preset-fbjs@2.1.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/babel-preset-fbjs
npm ERR! extraneous: base64-js@1.2.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/base64-js
npm ERR! extraneous: connect@2.30.2 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/connect
npm ERR! extraneous: denodeify@1.2.1 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/denodeify
npm ERR! extraneous: event-target-shim@1.1.1 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/event-target-shim
npm ERR! extraneous: fbjs-scripts@0.7.1 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/fbjs-scripts
npm ERR! extraneous: fs-extra@0.26.7 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/fs-extra
npm ERR! extraneous: image-size@0.3.5 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/image-size
npm ERR! extraneous: immutable@3.7.6 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/immutable
npm ERR! extraneous: inquirer@0.12.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/inquirer
npm ERR! extraneous: jest-haste-map@15.0.1 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/jest-haste-map
npm ERR! extraneous: joi@6.10.1 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/joi
npm ERR! extraneous: json5@0.4.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/json5
npm ERR! extraneous: jstransform@11.0.3 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/jstransform
npm ERR! extraneous: lodash@3.10.1 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/lodash
npm ERR! extraneous: mime@1.3.4 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/mime
npm ERR! extraneous: mime-types@2.1.11 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/mime-types
npm ERR! extraneous: module-deps@3.9.1 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/module-deps
npm ERR! extraneous: npmlog@2.0.4 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/npmlog
npm ERR! extraneous: opn@3.0.3 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/opn
npm ERR! extraneous: plist@1.2.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/plist
npm ERR! extraneous: progress@1.1.8 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/progress
npm ERR! extraneous: rebound@0.0.13 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/rebound
npm ERR! extraneous: regenerator-runtime@0.9.6 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/regenerator-runtime
npm ERR! extraneous: stacktrace-parser@0.1.4 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/stacktrace-parser
npm ERR! extraneous: temp@0.8.3 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/temp
npm ERR! extraneous: whatwg-fetch@1.1.1 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/whatwg-fetch
npm ERR! extraneous: ws@1.1.1 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/ws
npm ERR! extraneous: xcode@0.8.9 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/xcode
npm ERR! extraneous: xmldoc@0.4.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/xmldoc
npm ERR! extraneous: yargs@3.32.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/yargs
npm ERR! extraneous: yeoman-environment@1.5.3 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/yeoman-environment
npm ERR! extraneous: yeoman-generator@0.21.2 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/yeoman-generator
npm ERR! extraneous: react-native-maps@0.11.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/react-native-maps
npm ERR! extraneous: react-native-svg@4.3.0 /Users/jinteki/Projects/vanilla-exponent/node_modules/react-native-svg
npm ERR! missing: react-native-maps@git+https://github.com/exponent/react-native-maps.git#12853f0, required by exponent@12.0.5
npm ERR! missing: react-native-svg@git+https://github.com/exponent/react-native-svg.git#51ff90cc, required by exponent@12.0.5
npm ERR! missing: jest-resolve@git+https://github.com/exponentjs/jest-resolve.git, required by jest-exponent@0.1.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: react@^15.4.2, required by react-test-renderer@15.4.2
```

Answer (score 4):

upgrading to the latest NPM version (4.1) fixed this for me (can be done with `npm install -g npm`)